# E-mail id not capturing for most of the user in some user it is working correct. I am Using facebook grph api php

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, facebook-graph-api

Here I want to implement facebook login to my login. I table I have maintained e-mail as primary Key which is required for me. As I am using facebook Graph API using Php for some user I am getting e-mail but for most of the user, I am not getting an email. In place of email, I am getting NULL or Undefined.
Here is my code.

```
'<span onClick="loginfb()" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-social btn-
facebook" style="font: normal Arial;">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook</span>'

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '1698475113785794',
xfbml      : true, 
version    : 'v2.8'
});};
(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function loginfb(){
FB.login(function(response){
if(response.status=="connected"){
    getdetail();
}
},{scope: 'public_profile,email'});
}
function getdetail(){
FB.api('/me?fields=name,first_name, last_name, email, gender, id, 
birthday,link, education, picture, timezone', function(response){
var first_name=response.first_name;
var last_name=response.last_name;
var email=response.email;
var dob=response.birthday;
var gender=response.gender;
var education=response.education;
var pic=response.picture.data.url;
var time=response.timezone;
var fid=response.id;
var username=response.name;
alert(first_name+' '+last_name+' '+email+' '+dob+' '+gender+' '+pic+' '+time+' '+fid+' '+username);
});    
}
```

If I am alerting all the variable in place of email I am getting Undefined

Comment: Do not use the email address as primary identifier - use the app-scoped user id your get from the API. A lot of users do not even have an email address on file with Facebook - f.e. those that registered using only their mobile.

Comment: We have another option which I have seen on another website that if anyone having email as private then we can request him/her to share private email id with us. How I can implement this????